# View Engine (ViewNotFoundException) Error using Nancy

Tags: nancy, viewengine

I am trying to use **View Engine** to return an HTML page in my window application. URL gets called but when i try to return a View, i get **ViewNotFoundException** error.

In an error message, I cant see the extensions available and locations inspected but i still get an error as Below:

```
Nancy.RequestExecutionException: Oh noes! ---> Nancy.ViewEngines.ViewNotFoundException: Unable to locate view 'test' Currently available view engine extensions: sshtml,html,htm,cshtml,vbhtml
```

I have checked the Demo project on git and it works fine but that's a web project whereas mine is window service (i might be missing something). Has anyone tried to implement **View Engine** in windows service and got it working.

Error is quite self-explanatory but i cant seems to get my head around where the **test** file should go for it to work.

**Edit:**
Nancy version: 1.4.2

I tried **var foo = typeof(RazorViewEngine);** and it does return all the View Engine values with locations inspected and all that.

My Project structure is:

`Modules
 ---- myModule.cs
 Views
 ---- Test.cshtml`

**views/test** is in locations inspected but it looks like, its looking somewhere instead of my structure.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please more details: `Project structure, Nancy version etc`. Also have you seen: https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/View-location-conventions

Comment: @zulq I have looked into location-convention link (thanks) and added couple of entries. Now in an error, it looking at only those location which i have mentioned in ConfigureConventions but i still get the same error.

Comment: Have you installed the Razor view engine nuget package?

Comment: Yes, The problem was "copy to output dir" was not set to "copy always" for template files. All fixed